# Android : Wallpaper not properly fit on tablet screen

Tags: android, android-layout, pixel, live-wallpaper

I have one image which i need to set as device wallpaper from drawable folder.
I created one demo application in which oncreate of activity i just wrote code for set wallpaper of device as that particular image.

But when I set this image as wallpaper its either zoom or cropped. I want image should fit on screen size. In some devices it works in some it does not.

Moreover when i rotate my device at that time also wallpaper gone or some part of that cropped.

I have image resolution is `600*1024` pixels. I have samsung galaxy tab 2 that is also have same `Size  600 x 1024 pixels, 7.0 inches (~170 ppi pixel density)`.

But its not working. Please help me to sort out this issue.

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_WALLPAPER_HINTS"/>
```

**permission in manifest**